# psychopg2 to generate insert statements with variable column counts

Tags: python, sql, parameterized

I am attempting to insert Excel spreadsheets into a Postgres DB using a Python script with psychopg2.

The problem is not all the spreadsheets have the same number of columns, and I need the insert statement to be flexible enough so I don't have to specify them by name.

My approach is to load the columns of the spreadsheet's header row into a tuple, and likewise with the values being inserted.  So for example:

```
sql = ''''INSERT INTO my_table (%s) VALUES (%s);'''
cur.execute(sql, (cols, vals))
```

where 'cols' and 'vals' are both tuples.

'cols' can have 7, 9, 10, etc. entries, again depending on how many columns the spreadsheet had.

When I attempt to run this, I get:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'INSERT INTO my_table 
(ARRAY['"
LINE 1: 'INSERT INTO my_table...
    ^
```

Not sure if the problem is in my calling syntax, or if you simply can't do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's an apostrophe `'` at the beginning of your sql query.

```
''''INSERT INTO my_table (%s) VALUES (%s);'''
```

should be

```
'''INSERT INTO my_table (%s) VALUES (%s);'''
```

---

**Edit:** didn't realize you where trying to query columns dynamically. To do that, you should use text formatting. Asuming `cols` is a list:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO my_table ({}) VALUES (%s)'''.format(','.join(cols))
```

Then, your execution would be:

```
cur.execute(sql, (vals,))
```

Comment: Good eye ... sorry for the stupid typo.  I removed it but the error remains exactly as described.